# OpenProject api authentication using account username and password

Tags: authentication, openproject

Is it possible to make authenticated requests to OpenProject api using admin account username and password? I am currently trying Basic Authentication using username and password but invalid credentials error is received. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
Edit:
I tried as mentioned in the answer. This what I did:
Changed the configuration.yml file as given:

```
default:

      rails_cache_store: <%= ENV.fetch('RAILS_CACHE_STORE') { :memcache }.to_sym %>
      session_store: <%= ENV.fetch('SESSION_STORE') { :cache_store }.to_sym %>
      email_delivery_method: <%= ENV.fetch('EMAIL_DELIVERY_METHOD') { :sendmail } %>
      smtp_address: <%= ENV['SMTP_HOST'] %>
      smtp_port: <%= ENV.fetch('SMTP_PORT') { 25 }.to_i %>
      smtp_domain: <%= ENV.fetch('SMTP_DOMAIN') { ENV['HOSTNAME'] } %>
      smtp_authentication: <%= ENV.fetch('SMTP_AUTHENTICATION') { :login }.to_sym %>
      smtp_user_name: <%= ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'] %>
      smtp_password: <%= ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'] %>
      smtp_enable_starttls_auto: <%= ENV.fetch('SMTP_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO') { "false" } %>
      attachments_storage_path: <%= ENV.fetch('ATTACHMENTS_STORAGE_PATH') { "/var/db/_APP_NAME_/files" } %>
      global_basic_auth:
         user: admin
         password: admin
```

Then made a basic auth api call with username and password both admin. But still the authentication didnt work. Should there be any other headers to be included?

Comment: Any update regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement in the configuration.yml should read:

```
default:
  ...other configuration params...
  authentication:
    global_basic_auth:
      user: admin
      password: admin
```

The `authentication`-key is missing.

Once you have defined credentials in the [configuration.yml](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/dev/config/configuration.yml.example#L336) correctly, which will grant admin privileges, you should be able to issue calls against the api using basic auth, e.g.: `curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:3000/api/v3/users`. Bear in mind, that using the `-u` option, curl already transforms the HTTP-header value correctly (`Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` in this example). If you use anything other than curl, please ensure that the client sends the header value with `username:password` base64 encoded.

Please note, that you also have the option to define an api key per user as  [described by the documentation](http://docs.openproject.org/apiv3-doc/#header-api-key-through-basic-auth). Doing this, you can control the access rights of the user from granting him admin permissions to only limited permissions inside a specific project.

Comment: I too prefer the first method but I cannot use it since it is account specific and that it can be reset by the user from his/her OP account and I am dealing with dynamic OP accounts using SSO functionality. I think the second method is what I need, I will check it and get back to you. Anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer with what I have tried. Please check!! Thanks!

Comment: The authentication key was the issue. Now it's working. Thanks a lot mate!